# How to store json response from twitter Rest API to ng-repeat in angular from local storage

Tags: json, angularjs, cordova, twitter

I m trying to store the json res from twitter home timeline in localStorage and ng-repeat it but it seems not working . i tried json.stringify to store in localStorage and json.parse it from localStorage and store it in $scope.tweets and ng-repeating it. but not working

JS part

```
window.localStorage.setItem("tweets", JSON.stringify(data));
    var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tweets'));
    $scope.tweets = localData;
```

HTML part

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="i in tweets">

        <div class="item item-avatar"> 
            <img ng-src="{{ i.user.profile_image_url }}">
            <span class="card-title" ng-bind="i.user.name "></span>
            <i class="screen-name">@{{ i.user.screen_name }}</i>
            <p class="card-content " ng-bind="i.text"></p>
            <span class="tweet-time" ng-bind="i.created_at | date:'medium' "></span>
            <i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i>
            <img src="img/reply_tweet.png" class="right space" ng-click="">
            <img src="img/retweet.png" class="right space" ng-click="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it is working fine with basic html and object, here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f?p=preview)... I think it is not related with localstroge or angularjs...

Comment: I know its working in basic thing, the problem is that i am getting twitter feeds response as json and i tried above method. it not repeating the data

Comment: can you share response from twitter?

Comment: window.localStorage.setItem("tweets",JSON.stringify(data)); var localData = window.localStorage.getItem("tweets"); $scope.tweets = JSON.parse(localData); $scope.$apply();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really see what's wrong but here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/AltFjma8dttX3iP1iDni?p=preview

I'm assuming you're writing to local storage somewhere and reading from it in another place. If that's the case, it's important to create a watch that watches local storage, as I show below.

```
var data = ["One","Two","Three"];
$window.localStorage.setItem("tweets", JSON.stringify(data));

$scope.addData = function() {
  data.push($scope.newDataItem);
  $window.localStorage.setItem("tweets", JSON.stringify(data));
}

$scope.$watch(function() {
  return $window.localStorage.getItem('tweets');
}, function(lsData) {
  $scope.tweets = JSON.parse(lsData);
});
```

Comment: Hey @Pieter thanks for your reply , i tried your method, still the ng-repeat is not populating the data. I am posting my code have a look at it

Comment: window.localStorage.setItem("tweets",JSON.stringify(data));
var localData = window.localStorage.getItem("tweets");
$scope.tweets = JSON.parse(localData);
$scope.$apply();